# Media player play all files in listbox how?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, media-player

I have a listbox that contains all media files that has to be played. How do make media player play 1 by one?
This code plays 1 song but foreach is supposed to play all files, but I quess that is because it doesn't wait till media ended..
this code:

`Listbox = listBox3`

`listBox3Dict[s]` = string for all files in listbox

```
            Dictionary<string, string> listBox3Dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

>         private bool listbox3job()
>         {
>             AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer axWmp = wfh.Child as AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer;
>                 {
>                     foreach (var selected in listBox3.Items)
>                     {
>                         string s = selected.ToString();
> 
>                         if (listBox3Dict.ContainsKey(s))
>                         {
WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist playlist = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.newPlaylist("myPlaylist", string.Empty);
                            // you can add songs to url on for loop 
                            WMPLib.IWMPMedia temp = this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia(listBox3Dict[s]); //Load media from URL. 
                            playlist.appendItem(temp); //Add song to playlist.
                            // after you add all songs set the new playlist
                            this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.autoStart = true; //not necessary
                            this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentPlaylist = playlist; //Set media player to use the playlist.
>                         }
>                     }
> 
>                 return true;
>             }
>             return false;
>         }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you can do is create player list and start play that list

```
private bool listbox3job()
{

    AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer axWmp = wfh.Child as AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer;
    WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist playlist = axWmp.newPlaylist("myPlaylist", string.Empty);

    foreach (var selected in listBox1.Items)
    {
        string s = selected.ToString();
        if (listBox3Dict.ContainsKey(s))
        {
            WMPLib.IWMPMedia temp = axWmp.newMedia(listBox3Dict[s]); //Load media from URL. 
            playlist.appendItem(temp); //Add song to playlist.
        }
    }
    axWmp.settings.autoStart = true; //not necessary
    axWmp.currentPlaylist = playlist; //Set media player to use the playlist.
    return true;
}
```

http://www.timwylie.com/playlist.html

Comment: I don't know how to make a playlist. Maybe you can help me?

Comment: Thank you for code!
But it seems that IWMPPlaylis does not exist?
And it can't find the name "p" either?

Comment: You need to have reference to AxWMPLib and WMPLib

Comment: First of all. Thank you for helping me...
I have changed the code but It won't start the media!

Check my updated code!

Comment: @Sneakybastardd You create play list for each song, check my updated answer, you need to have list box with correct song paths like `C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\Kalimba.mp3`

Comment: It finds all media but I get an error on this line : 
WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist playlist = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.newPlaylist("myPlaylist", string.Empty);


Error code : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: what is `wfh` in your code? and how you add media player to your program?

Comment: I use a separate WPF usercontroll named WmpAxControl.cs
The media player is there.

Comment: I use a Windows form host that calls the Media player to be compatible with WPF:

<WindowsFormsHost Name="wfh">
      <ax:AxWindowsMediaPlayer x:Name="axWmp"/>
    </WindowsFormsHost>

Answer (score 0):

Earlier I was working on a set of speech files in a list. I used PlayStateChange event. From this event you can find MediaEnded state where you can reassign the playfile to next item in the list.